# How do I retrieve values from an XML that (I think) doesn't have standard formatting?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can't seem to find an article with this same problem.

I have an XML file like this:

```
<user id="" name="" termsofuse="http://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse">
<firstname value="" /> 
<lastname value="" /> 
<avatarlink value="N/A" /> 
<yearregistered value="" /> 
<lastlogin value="2012-10-04" /> 
<stateorprovince value="" /> 
<country value="" /> 
<webaddress value="" /> 
<xboxaccount value="" /> 
<wiiaccount value="" /> 
<psnaccount value="" /> 
<battlenetaccount value="" /> 
<steamaccount value="" /> 
<traderating value="363" /> 
</user>
```

And I am using the following code to extract the data:

```
static string QueryTheData(XDocument doc)
{
  var data = from item in doc.Descendants("user")
             select new
             {
               avatarlink = item.Element("avatarlink").Value,
               lastlogin = item.Element("lastlogin").Value,
             };
  var t = "";
  foreach (var p in data)
    t += p.ToString();
  return t;
}
```

But my values returned are null. I'm wondering if it's because the XML file begins:

```
<user id="" name="" termsofuse="http://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse">
```

Whereas in all the examples I have found the XML begins like this:

```
<user> ... etc
```

How can I read these values in this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get the value of attribute `value`. Try this

```
avatarlink = item.Element("avatarlink").Attribute("value").Value
```

But I would go this way

```
var list = doc.Descendants("user")
        .Select(u=>u.Elements().ToDictionary(e=>e.Name.LocalName,e=>e.Attribute("value").Value))
        .ToList();
```

where every item of the final list contains a dictionary of elements and their values

```
var lastlogin = list[0]["lastlogin"];
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the result would look like? I'm not too experienced with lambda expressions yet.

Comment: @Bob. its type is `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`

Comment: I second that, this is neat! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Value attribute is reading the value of the node, you are probably looking for something like:

```
(string)item.Element("avatarlink").Attribute("value")
```